# Improving C code to remove copy-paste

Tags: c, cs50

P.S. Some people had issues understanding the question 'how to improve my code'. I couldn't have made it clearer, really. I solved the issue in the meantime.

I'm working on an assignment to recover photos from a cd card file (.raw) by first finding them by their 'magic numbers'. It's a part of a CS50 class if anybody knows what it is.

Anyway, it seems to work ok-ish. I can recover all photos, but some of them of a worse quality, then others (a lot of white pixels) - not sure if it's intended.

In the code depending on conditions I open and close jpg files to write info into them. I can't figure out a way to avoid copy-paste to fopen, fwrite and fclose the file. I'd like to improve this part. Here's the code:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(void)
{
    // open input file 
    FILE* card_file = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (card_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open card.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

// declare output file
FILE* image;

// array to store values we read for each 512 bytes
BYTE buffer[512];

// number of jpg files found
int jpgs = 0;

// variable used to create new files
char title[10];

// execute until the end of file is reached
while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card_file) > 0)
{
    // find a new jpg file by its magic numbers
    if((buffer[0] == 0xff) && (buffer[1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff))
    {
        //create a new file if it's found
        sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", jpgs);
        jpgs++;

        //open the file and check if file is opened correctly
        image = fopen(title, "a");

        if (image == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %03d.jpg\n", jpgs);
            return 2;
        }

        // write into the file and close it
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
        fclose(image);
    }
    else 
    {
        //check if a jpg file was already found before
        if(jpgs > 0)
        {
            //open the file and check if file is opened correctly
            image = fopen(title, "a");

            if (image == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %03d.jpg\n", jpgs);
                return 2;
            }

            // write into the file and close it
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
            fclose(image);
        }
    }
}

//close the input file
fclose(card_file);

}
```

I tried to create a separate function, but couldn't figure out how to handle pointer to integer values I need to pass to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just put it in a function (which you pass the buffer and filename to)?

Comment: Copy-past is a matter of the editor; how is that related to C? Your question is not clear. If you want to re-use code, start learning about functions.

Comment: Hi Olaf, copy-paste as in 'if I need to copy-paste some code in my program, it means that there's a better way to do it'. I just wanted to improve my code, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things that need to be passed by reference are the `title` and `buffer`, you need to return a boolean that we can test to allow the `return 2;` on the caller.

```
int appendBuffer(char *title, BYTE *buffer)
{
    //open the file and check if file is opened correctly
    FILE* image = fopen(title, "a");

    if (image == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", title); //note reuse of title now
        return 0; //it didn't work
    }

    // write into the file and close it
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
    fclose(image);
    return 1; //it worked
}
```

Usage:

```
// find a new jpg file by its magic numbers
if((buffer[0] == 0xff) && (buffer[1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff))
{
    //create a new file if it's found
    sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", jpgs);
    jpgs++;

    if (!appendBuffer(title, buffer)) return 2;
}
else 
{
    //check if a jpg file was already found before
    if(jpgs > 0)
    {
       if (!appendBuffer(title, buffer)) return 2;
    }
}
```

Another idea for comparing many sequential bytes, use `memcmp` rather than `&&` chains:

```
const char magic[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};

// find a new jpg file by its magic numbers
if (memcmp(buffer, magic, 3) == 0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I had issues with creating a function here (bunch of errors I couldn't understand). I'll try out your method to better understand how the function works.
In the meantime, I've rewrote my if conditions. The first if now only contains 'create a new file' code, and the second if condition contains the 'open the file and check if file is opened correctly'. So no copy-paste was needed to begin with!